# Reading text files within specific number of characters in each line

Tags: java, text-files, netbeans-7, jtextfield

I'm trying to read text from text files and I can already print it on system by using system.out.print. But if I set the text of the JTextArea from the text that I've read on the text file, it shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". It's actually running good in printing lines and i can already read what I want but, I can't put this text on JTextArea. What should I do?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 package mdiforms;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    public class FR 
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
            String path  = ("C:/Users/Pasusani/Desktop/try.txt");
    FileReader file = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String text = "";
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line !=null)
    {
        text += line;
        line = reader.readLine();
               String setText = line.substring(0,1);
             txtLine.setText(setText); 
    }
    System.out.println(text);

    }       

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet where you are trying to put it into the JTextArea?

Comment: Please post your real code. `txtLine` comes from nowhere.

Comment: You didn't initialize `txtLine`, probably.

Comment: private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea txtLine;
    public static javax.swing.JTable wa;

Comment: txtLine sir is a JTextArea

Comment: Too much code for a comment. Please edit your question and add the new code from your comment

Comment: Heres my question sir: How to read specific number of characters in a line within a text file and set “read characters” to JTextArea

Answer (score 0):

your JTextArea txtLine object is not initialized, try using `txtLine = new javax.swing.JTextArea();`

Answer (score 0):

Redirect output stream to jTextArea and set output stream like this:

```
    ....
    {
    OutputStream out1 = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextPane(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextPane(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out1, true));
  }
  ....

  private void updateTextPane(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Document doc = jTextArea.getDocument();
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, null);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

now use `System.out.println(text);` It will print text to `jTextArea` not on Console.